# C# Gmail Compatibility View

Tags: c#, browser, gmail

I have created a custom web browser to integrate in to our software and loaded gmail. I am getting this message at the top of gmail:

> It looks like you have enabled
> Internet Explorer Compatibility View.
>
> Gmail works best if you turn this off.
> Learn how to do this.
>
> 1.Open the Tools menu and select Compatibility View Settings.
>
> 2.Select 'google.com' under 'Websites you've added to Compatibility View'.
>
> 3.Click Remove.

Is there a way to prevent this message from coming up or to turn that option off? I don't see that in the browser control as an option.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using the IE-based WebBrowser control ?

Comment: I am using the MS.Net 4.0 Browser component. Assembly:  System.Windows.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll) Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be changed by adding registry keys.

See the relevant post from IE blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx

Quoting parts of it:

> We’ve made a few improvements to our
>   extensibility model in IE8 RC1 based
>   on feedback we’ve received both
>   internally and externally.
>
> WebBrowser (WebOC) Rendering Mode
>   Changes
>
> About a year ago, I posted an entry
>   talking about WebBrowser Control
>   Rendering Modes in IE8. You may recall
>   that applications using the WebBrowser
>   Control (also known as the WebOC, or
>   Trident hosts) can use a Feature
>   Control Key to select the default
>   rendering mode of webpages they load.
>
> Since our release of IE8 Beta 1, we’ve
>   changed the name of the Feature
>   Control Key that is used to toggle
>   that behavior. The key was previously
>   called FEATURE_NATIVE_DOCUMENT_MODE.
>   IE8 now refers to it by the key
>   FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION, and the
>   values for both IE7 Standards Mode and
>   IE8 Standards Mode have changed.
>
> For compatibility purposes, the
>   WebBrowser control will run in IE7
>   Standards Mode by default if no
>   Feature Control Key value is defined
>   for an application. To run a
>   WebBrowser control in IE8 Standards
>   Mode, use the following new value into
>   the registry:
>
> [(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "MyApplication.exe" = dword 8000 (Hex:
>   0x1F40)
>
> To run in IE7 Standards Mode, use the
>   following registry value:
>
> [(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "MyApplication.exe" = dword 7000 (Hex:
>   0x1B58)
>
> For IE8 RTM, we’ve added a new
>   “forced” IE8 Standards Mode value.
>   When an application opts into this
>   mode, the Web Browser control will use
>   the IE8 User-Agent string and Browser
>   Emulation mode strictly. It will also
>   ignore fallback features such as the
>   built-in Compatibility View list and
>   the user-generated Compatibility View
>   list when loading pages. To run in
>   “forced” IE8 Standards Mode, use the
>   following registry value:
>
> [(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "MyApplication.exe" = dword 8888 (Hex:
>   0x22B8)
>
> In all of these examples,
>   “MyApplication.exe” refers to the name
>   of your application.